# add dynamic button to xml in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

First, this is my MainPageViewer:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);

MyPageAdapter adapter = new MyPageAdapter();
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
pager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

The Adapter for my PageViewer is here:

```
  public int getCount()
        {
            return 3;
        }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int resId = 0;

        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.blogandbericht;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.blogandbericht;
                break;
            case 2:
                resId = R.layout.blogandbericht;
                break;
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2)
    {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1)
    {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

(Yes i know, that all layout are "bloganbericht")

And this my blogandbericht:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/masterSv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#8ad5f0">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/masterLl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="foo bar"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

all works fine. I can see the three buttons on each layout.
But how can i add views like textview or button to the layout dynamicly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the viewpager only supports 1 view inside each page, so in the adapter you modify the method:

```
public Object instantiateItem( View pager, int position )
```

you can create the view inside this method and return it to like this:

```
WebView web = new WebView(mContext);
return web;
```

Or if you need a more complex view than just an "Object" then you can create a linear layout, or something similar and add your other views inside and return that view like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
WebView web = new WebView(mContext);
Button btn = new Button(mContext);
layout.addView(web);
layout.addView(btn);
return layout;
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE:**

Well right now i am doing something similar, i make the view that i will add to the viewpager dynamic, so depending on the type of an object i determine what is going to be inside.
I do not know how you plan to determine how a page must look, but i will tell you how i do it.

I have a list of "Objects", and those objects extends from a Class (You can also do it with interface and implementation, i do it with extends for other reasons) in common, and that class have a method "public View getView()" and the in all the Classes that extends from the Father Class (or Implemented the Interface), you Override (Implement) the method and add the code necessary to make that "PAGE" look like you want, then on the adapter you only need to have a list of "Objects" of any of the classes that you created and depending on which type each of those "Objects" are they will create the View passed to the ViewPager.

**EXAMPLE:**

Dog  //CLASS OR INTERFACE WITH METHOD *getView()*

-Chihuahua   //This return a WebView

-Sharpei     //This return a HorizontalListView

-Huskie      //This return a LinerLayout with a Bunch of Views Inside

on your adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
     List<Dog> Doggies = new ArrayList<Dog>();

     public ViewPagerAdapter( Context context ){
          Doggies.add(new Chihuahua());
          Doggies.add(new Sharpei());
          Doggies.add(new Chihuahua());
          Doggies.add(new Huskie());
          Doggies.add(new Huskie());
          Doggies.add(new Chihuahua());
          Doggies.add(new Sharpei());
     }

     //and last but not least, on your onCreate method in your adapter:

     public Object instantiateItem( View pager, int position ){ 
          return Doggies.get(position).getView();
     }

     /*THE REST OF THE METHODS GOES AFTER THIS*/

 }  //END OF ADAPTER
```

Comment: yes this works. but the problem is that all pages have the same linearlayout. How can i say: "Add two buttons to layout A" and "Add WebView to layout B" and "add 3 buttons to layout c"?

Comment: Well i already updated my answer, and if you can marked as Answer that would be better for anyone having the same problem. If you have another problem let me know, and i will see if i can help you with it.